# Insert multiple Records of same type at once in Google Cloud End Points

Tags: java, json, rest, google-app-engine, jdo

I have created a google cloud endpoint api which takes one record at a time as a JSON. Following is the insertMethod

```
@ApiMethod(name = "insertRecord")
public Record insertRecord(Record record) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        if(record.getSyncTime() == null)
            record.setSyncTime(new Date());
        mgr.makePersistent(record);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return error;
}
```

If we post a JSON in below format, it would add the record in data store.

```
{
    ipAddress: "123.456.789.098",
    user: "buddha",
    message: "testing a single record adding"
}
```

I'm curious to know How I can write the method that would take multiple records in a single JSON request?

I tried changing method to take a List but I got an error saying that I should not pass Array or List.

Comment: Good question.  There seems [(docs)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/paramreturn_types) to be a distinction between _parameter types_ (which *can* be arrays or `Collection` of `String`, for example) and _entity types_, for which "there can only be a single entity parameter per method".  Looking at your code, I think you'd be trying to supply multiple request entities via your List.  An `@ApiTransformer` [(docs)](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/endpoints/annotations#apitransformer) may help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trial and errors, I have solved the problem by following below Approach.

I have created another Class that contains a List of Records as below.

```
public class RecordList {
    List<Record> records;

    public List<Record> getRecords() {
        return records;
    }

    public void setRecords(List<Record> records) {
        this.records= records;
    }
}
```

I have created another API method that takes this this new object as a parameter

```
@ApiMethod(name = "insertRecordList")
public RecordList insertRecordList(RecordList records) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        for(Record record : records.getRecords()){
            if(record.getSyncTime() == null)
                record.setSyncTime(new Date());
        }
        mgr.makePersistentAll(records.getRecords());
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return records;
}
```

With this, I'm able to pass JSON request as below to insert multiple items at once...

```
{
  records:[
    {
      "host": "testlist",
      "ipAddress": "sadf",
      "message": "testlist"
    },
    {
      "host": "h",
      "ipAddress": "1",
      "message": "another"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: makePersistentAll(Collection) may help that ;-)

Comment: is it, let me check... Yes it would certainly help if it works.